# Event log filling up with Sql error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, service-broker

Windows event log filling up with

> ERROR 1: "The activated proc '[dbo].[SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure-]' running on queue 'test.dbo.SqlQueryNotificationService-' output the following: 'Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.'"

And

> Error 2: An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue. Error: 15517, State: 1. Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

I am using  SQL Server 2017. I have tried changing owner of the database, but still receive error messages. If service broker disabled error stops, but I want to use SQL service broker feature.
Is there any other method to solve this error.

Comment: Please check this link --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823354/sql-server-principal-dbo-does-not-exist

Comment: You must still have service broker enabled in some other location and it's calling with bad code. 'dbo' is a role, not a login. It should be there, regardless of who owns the db or is in the role.

Comment: can you run `test.dbo.SqlQueryNotificationService` successfully in a query window in SSMS?

Comment: This question is from 2020 - are you *still* having the exact same problem?

Comment: Yes, if we enable service broker we are getting same error.